# Facebook Feed dialog loses Youtube path and parameters? (iPhone SDK)

Tags: iphone, youtube, fbconnect

Trying to use the Feed dialog to post a Youtube link. I'm putting the video URL in as the "source" parameter, but it seems as though it's stripping off the `watch?v=...` -- what's uploaded (in fact, what's visible already in the Feed dialog itself) is just "www.youtube.com". Is there a trick here I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so: it looks like I was using the wrong URL for the `source`, but that wasn't the whole story; you need to set `source` *and* `link` *and* `picture` if you really want this to work.   E.g.:

```
source  : http://www.youtube.com/v/r3zlp3Ok7F8
link    : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r3zlp3Ok7F8
picture : http://img.youtube.com/vi/r3zlp3Ok7F8/default.jpg
```

What I thought was the `source` is actually the `link`, and the `link` and the `picture` are both special URLs. Substitute the video ID in all three.

Comment: Wow that has to be very specific. It even requires the www. For the record, link is not required to point to the video if you want to some other page w/ the video. Thanks for your help.